# Rotating a matrix in Go

Tags: go, debugging, matrix

I'm trying to rotate a matrix by 90° clockwise, specifically with a not-in-place rotate algorithm. I've come up with this code:

```
func RotateClockWiseNIP(matrix [][]int) (out [][]int) {
    // Create and populate a new out matrix full of zero
    nullRow := []int{}
    for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
        nullRow = append(nullRow, 0)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
        out = append(out, nullRow)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
    // Change values accordingly
    for row := 0; row < len(matrix); row++ {
        for c := 0; c < len(matrix); c++ {
            fmt.Printf("The matrix element %v %v goes to out element %v %v\n", row, c, c, len(matrix)-1-row)
            out[c][len(matrix)-1-row] = matrix[row][c]
            fmt.Println(out)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

The idea is to take each row and place it as column in the new matrix. So for instance the first row will be the last column, the second row would be the second last column and so on.
Now the code works, but not as expected. Printing out the results for a matrix `[][]int{{1,2},{3,4}` gives out this:

```
[[0 0] [0 0]]
The matrix element 0 0 goes to out element 0 1
[[0 1] [0 1]]
The matrix element 0 1 goes to out element 1 1
[[0 2] [0 2]]
The matrix element 1 0 goes to out element 0 0
[[3 2] [3 2]]
The matrix element 1 1 goes to out element 1 0
[[4 2] [4 2]]
```

You can see that each assignment it's repeated on both rows, instead of just to its right position in the `out` matrix.
Any hint about why this happens?
Thank you so much !

------------------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------------------------

Ok apparently the problem was on the first part. Swapping

```
nullRow := []int{}
    for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
        nullRow = append(nullRow, 0)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
        out = append(out, nullRow)
    }
```

for

```
for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
    out = append(out, []int{})
    for j := 0; j < len(matrix); j++ {
        out[i] = append(out[i], 0)
    }
}
```

solved the problem. I'll leave the question though, because I really can't understand what was wrong in the first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the same slice `nullRow` to all rows in your first approach. Slice has underlying values with a pointer. So all the rows have the same values.